# OpenGL ES: Shadow Mapping

Tags: opengl-es, mapping, shadow

I am working a long time know, to get shadows in my project. But there is still some problems I hope you can help me with.

[image]

the sun is actually 10 behind me, 200 over me and is moving from left to right to the edges from the map.

I am updating the orthogonal Projection like this:

```
    GLfloat orto_posX = cam.x - sun_position.x;
    orthoMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(orto_posX-10.0, orto_posX+10.0,-SUN_DISTANCE_Y, -SUN_DISTANCE_Y+MAX_HEIGHT, cam.z - 10.0 , cam.z + 100.0);
```

At first there is this problem with this black "board", I don't know how to call it.
Than I have surtend black areas on the ground.
And I need somehow a different angle of view. I mean the sun is moving from left to right the hole time, the shadows are not moving, and the right frame is stuck like that the hole time.

These are the shaders:

```
attribute vec4 position;

//Matrixes
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix *  viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision highp float;

void main()
{
    highp float depth = gl_FragCoord.z;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(depth), 1.0);
}
```

Nothing special. my projectionMatrix ist the orthoMatrix, I am updating and the viewMatrix ist the position of the sun.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the projection matrix. You need to update the view matrix when rendering from the point of view of the sun (into the shadow map) based on its location. Take a look at ShadowMapPass() in my tutorial: http://ogldev.org/www/tutorial23/tutorial23.html

Comment: I wrote your first tutorial about shadow mapping. And I will continue with the second part. But I am not sure if that is the same problem :S I am editing the post with my shaders

Comment: I need more kind of an rotation so the sun will from this angle to the field my camera is at. Or something like that. I can not explain it. But the somehow is the right View on the picture. from the sun-position but shifted with the ortho-Proj

Comment: I see you have a lot more tutorials there ^^I think that I have to generate such a UVN-Matrix like in your tutorial 13. I think that would help.

Comment: Ok, the Sun looks now to may camera position. But I have one more question. What is better to use für the projection the perspective or the orthogonal ? I am using the orthogonal and I don't get it to work as it seems. If the sun is moving something is coming out of the perspective all the time